# Detox_iOS_After building the app successfully getting an error for testNamePattern

Tags: javascript, ios, detox

After adding detox to a new ReactNative project, I run $`detox test` and get this:

> detox[76718] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/jest --config e2e/config.json '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 "e2e"

But I was not able to figure out why this is not working: **jest --config e2e/**

Comment: you should describe what are you doing exactly and what is wrong before sending the error message

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].